# Compile Error while building CPP with Pybind11 for Python in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, windows-10, pybind11

This query with respect to the tutorial titled [Create a C++ extension for Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/working-with-c-cpp-python-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2017#create-the-core-c-projects) in Microsoft Docs.

I have done all instructions as per the tutorial. I am using a Windows 10 64-bit and have multiple python versions installed, which I usually call `py -x.x-xx sample.py`. Over this I have installed Visual Studio 2017 with Python development option which includes both Python 3.6 32-bit and 64-bit.

There are two ways shown in the tutorial: (1) [**CPython extensions**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/working-with-c-cpp-python-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2017#cpython-extensions) and (2) [**Pybind11**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/working-with-c-cpp-python-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2017#pybind11). I am getting multiple errors with both of them. However, I have decided to pursue the **Pybind11** way and therefore listing the errors related to it, as it's cleaner and requires very little changes to an original C++ code.

This is the piece of `module.cpp` file:

```cpp
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cmath>

const double e = 2.7182818284590452353602874713527;

double sinh_impl(double x) {
    return (1 - pow(e, (-2 * x))) / (2 * pow(e, -x));
}

double cosh_impl(double x) {
    return (1 + pow(e, (-2 * x))) / (2 * pow(e, -x));
}

double tanh_impl(double x) {
    return sinh_impl(x) / cosh_impl(x);
}

namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(superfastcode2, m) {
    m.def("fast_tanh2", &tanh_impl, R"pbdoc(
        Compute a hyperbolic tangent of a single argument expressed in radians.
    )pbdoc");

#ifdef VERSION_INFO
    m.attr("__version__") = VERSION_INFO;
#else
    m.attr("__version__") = "dev";
#endif
}
```

When I try to build as per the instructions in the tutorial, the following is the error generated in the log:

```
  module.cpp
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\buffer_info.h(49): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'Py_buffer'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\buffer_info.h(49): error C2535: 'pybind11::buffer_info::buffer_info(void)': member function already defined or declared
  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\buffer_info.h(26): note: see declaration of 'pybind11::buffer_info::buffer_info'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\buffer_info.h(87): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\buffer_info.h(87): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\buffer_info.h(87): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\buffer_info.h(50): error C2065: 'view': undeclared identifier
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\buffer_info.h(51): error C2065: 'view': undeclared identifier
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\buffer_info.h(50): error C2661: 'pybind11::buffer_info::buffer_info': no overloaded function takes 2 arguments
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\buffer_info.h(52): error C2039: 'view': is not a member of 'pybind11::buffer_info'
  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\buffer_info.h(17): note: see declaration of 'pybind11::buffer_info'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\buffer_info.h(52): error C2065: 'view': undeclared identifier
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\buffer_info.h(71): error C2065: 'view': undeclared identifier
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\buffer_info.h(71): error C2039: 'view': is not a member of 'pybind11::buffer_info'
  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\buffer_info.h(17): note: see declaration of 'pybind11::buffer_info'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\buffer_info.h(77): error C2065: 'view': undeclared identifier
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\buffer_info.h(77): error C3861: 'PyBuffer_Release': identifier not found
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\buffer_info.h(77): error C2541: 'delete': cannot delete objects that are not pointers
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(406): error C3861: 'PyInstanceMethod_Check': identifier not found
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(407): error C3861: 'PyInstanceMethod_GET_FUNCTION': identifier not found
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(410): error C3861: 'PyMethod_Check': identifier not found
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(411): error C3861: 'PyMethod_GET_FUNCTION': identifier not found
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(613): error C2065: 'PyListObject': undeclared identifier
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(613): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(613): error C2612: trailing '(' illegal in base/member initializer list
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(678): error C2039: 'sequence_slow_readwrite': is not a member of 'pybind11::detail::iterator_policies'
  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(595): note: see declaration of 'pybind11::detail::iterator_policies'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(678): error C2065: 'sequence_slow_readwrite': undeclared identifier
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(678): error C2923: 'pybind11::detail::generic_iterator': 'sequence_slow_readwrite' is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'Policy'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(679): error C2039: 'dict_readonly': is not a member of 'pybind11::detail::iterator_policies'
  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(595): note: see declaration of 'pybind11::detail::iterator_policies'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(679): error C2065: 'dict_readonly': undeclared identifier
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(679): error C2923: 'pybind11::detail::generic_iterator': 'dict_readonly' is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'Policy'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(779): error C2027: use of undefined type '_typeobject'
  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\object.h(344): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(779): error C2065: '_PyObject_NextNotImplemented': undeclared identifier
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(832): error C2039: 'PyIterable_Check': is not a member of 'pybind11::detail'
  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(402): note: see declaration of 'pybind11::detail'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(832): error C3861: 'PyIterable_Check': identifier not found
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(839): error C2039: 'PyUnicode_Check_Permissive': is not a member of 'pybind11::detail'
  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(402): note: see declaration of 'pybind11::detail'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(839): error C3861: 'PyUnicode_Check_Permissive': identifier not found
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(934): error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'const pybind11::str' to 'pybind11::object'
  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(934): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(935): error C2027: use of undefined type 'pybind11::str'
  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(21): note: see declaration of 'pybind11::str'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(936): error C2027: use of undefined type 'pybind11::str'
  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(21): note: see declaration of 'pybind11::str'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(963): error C2039: 'PyNone_Check': is not a member of 'pybind11::detail'
  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(402): note: see declaration of 'pybind11::detail'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(963): error C3861: 'PyNone_Check': identifier not found
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(1012): error C2039: 'enable_if_t': is not a member of 'pybind11::detail::detail'
  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(984): note: see declaration of 'pybind11::detail::detail'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(1012): error C2947: expecting '>' to terminate template-parameter-list, found '<'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(1012): warning C4346: 'value': dependent name is not a type
  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(1012): note: prefix with 'typename' to indicate a type
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(1012): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'value'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(1013): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(1029): error C2039: 'enable_if_t': is not a member of 'pybind11::detail::detail'
  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(984): note: see declaration of 'pybind11::detail::detail'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(1029): error C2947: expecting '>' to terminate template-parameter-list, found '<'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(1029): warning C4346: 'value': dependent name is not a type
  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(1029): note: prefix with 'typename' to indicate a type
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(1029): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'value'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(1030): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(1301): error C2244: 'pybind11::detail::object_api<Derived>::begin': unable to match function definition to an existing declaration
  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(1301): note: see declaration of 'pybind11::detail::object_api<Derived>::begin'
  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(1301): note: definition
  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(1301): note: 'pybind11::detail::iterator pybind11::detail::object_api<Derived>::begin(void) const'
  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(1301): note: existing declarations
  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(1301): note: 'pybind11::iterator pybind11::detail::object_api<Derived>::begin(void) const'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(1302): error C2244: 'pybind11::detail::object_api<Derived>::end': unable to match function definition to an existing declaration
  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(1302): note: see declaration of 'pybind11::detail::object_api<Derived>::end'
  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(1302): note: definition
  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(1302): note: 'pybind11::detail::iterator pybind11::detail::object_api<Derived>::end(void) const'
  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(1302): note: existing declarations
  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(1302): note: 'pybind11::iterator pybind11::detail::object_api<Derived>::end(void) const'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(1303): error C2888: 'pybind11::detail::item_accessor pybind11::detail::object_api<Derived>::operator [](pybind11::handle) const': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'detail'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(1306): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(1306): error C2059: syntax error: 'const'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(1306): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(1306): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(1309): error C2888: 'pybind11::detail::obj_attr_accessor pybind11::detail::object_api<Derived>::attr(pybind11::handle) const': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'detail'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(1312): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(1312): error C2059: syntax error: 'const'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(1312): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(1312): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(1315): error C2888: 'pybind11::detail::args_proxy pybind11::detail::object_api<Derived>::operator *(void) const': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'detail'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(1317): error C2027: use of undefined type 'pybind11::detail::args_proxy'
  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(25): note: see declaration of 'pybind11::detail::args_proxy'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(1318): error C2888: 'bool pybind11::detail::object_api<Derived>::contains(T &&) const': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'detail'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(1323): error C2888: 'pybind11::str pybind11::detail::object_api<Derived>::str(void) const': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'detail'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(1323): error C2027: use of undefined type 'pybind11::str'
  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(21): note: see declaration of 'pybind11::str'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(1326): error C2888: 'pybind11::detail::str_attr_accessor pybind11::detail::object_api<Derived>::doc(void) const': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'detail'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\pytypes.h(1329): error C2888: 'pybind11::handle pybind11::detail::object_api<Derived>::get_type(void) const': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'detail'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_86\include\pybind11\detail\typeid.h(22): fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
```

Comment: Are all the include paths set up properly?

Comment: Yes. I checked it by removing #include <pybind11/pybind11.h>. It then gives an error saying the header file is not found. So I am sure it's reading the header file. The error starts once it goes into it. Even with just  #include <pybind11/pybind11.h> and no other other code specific to pybind11 it's giving a host of errors.

Comment: Then why did you post a code sample that is more than just an `#include`? Present a [MCVE] please with errors as _text_ not in an image or behind a link

Comment: You are removing the header and then it fails by telling you that the file is not found? Obviously it is still included from somewhere and cannot be found because the project is not set up properly. Add the path to pybind11 in the include path.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my comment. :-) I have already included the path to include folder : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_86\include . I getting the above error despite this path being included.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I have added possible smallest part of the code for reproducing the same errors. I have also replaced the error image with it's textual content as per your comments. Thanks!

Comment: From the error messages it looks like you might need to add an `#include <Python.h>` at the beginning of the `.cpp` file (as was done in the **CPython extensions** section).

Comment: @martineau Thank you for editing the question. I tried to include the 'Python.h' header but it is still giving the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem. After due flailing, I downloaded the repository associated with the tutorial on github: https://github.com/Microsoft/python-sample-vs-cpp-extension and went line-by-line through the project configuration. (Incidentally, their configuration uses the environmental variable PYTHONPATH instead of PYTHONHOME as directed in the tutorial.)

What fixed the problem for me was changing the pre-processor definitions to:
_WINDLL;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)
to match the repository version. The culprit seems to be the Py_LIMITED_API definition advised by the tutorial: when I add that to the list, the problem returns.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Let me try this out and I shall reply to you with the feedback and upvote your answer.

Comment: Thank you! Simply removing Py_LIMITED_API works for me as well (use Python 3.7 32-bit as recommended by the manual).

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you are trying to compile example with 32-bit Python, and it cannot compile the pybind11 within the Python installation.

By default I have the 64-bit Python installed alone with my VS2017.
So I've configured example for 64-bit like this.

In superfastcode2 go to:

C/C++ / General / Additional Include Directories - add
`$(PythonHome)Include` and `$(ProjectDir)pybind11-master`, the latest one must point the place where pybind11 is installed(download it as a ZIP file from GitHub, and unzip it into pybind11-master directory, I have it inside the superfastcode2 folder).
Linker / General - add `$(PythonHome)libs`

In superfastcode go to:

C/C++ / General / Additional Include Directories - add

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\include
```

Linker / General - add

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\libs
```

Add this workaround for Python.h in module.cpp :

```
//Workaround for - LNK1104: cannot open file 'python36_d.lib'

#define HAVE_RND  //This makes always use the Release version of Python, even in Debug mode

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define RESTORE_DEBUG
#undef _DEBUG
#endif

#include <Python.h>

#ifdef RESTORE_DEBUG
#define _DEBUG
#undef RESTORE_DEBUG
#endif
```

Fix the path to:

```
#include <include/pybind11/pybind11.h>
```

Should work then. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Same Problem! Finally I fixed it by changing [Configuration > Platform] to **x64** as I installed 64 bit version Python.

> Linker errors related to target architecture: change the C++ target's project architecture to match that of your Python installation. For example, if you're targeting x64 with the C++ project but your Python installation is x86, change the C++ project to target x86.